# how to set interval to execute tasks in PHP?

Tags: php, email, scheduled-tasks

i'm working on the newsletter subscribe system on my project, i need to run the script of sending mails to subscribers every week or any interval i set.

i would make a last_send filed in my database and make a check every time user visit the site, but this will be an extra load for user who will trigger the send mails script.

anyway to make the server do this every #TIME_INTERVAL# ?

some extra information:

> i'm using PHP 5.5 & PHPMailer to handle mails sending
>   and the final product will be used by different users on different hosts .

Comment: corn jobs is what you are looking for.

Comment: If you're on a linux environment, google crontab.

Comment: i'm using windows :/